# How to make grid lines the same colour as tick lines

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

See the below example plot, the tick lines are black while grid lines are grey.

[image: plot]

How can we make them the same?

Neither of these `GridColor` methods helped:

```
%set(gca, 'GridColor', [0 0 0]);
ax = gca;
ax.GridColor = [0 0 0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To change the tick marks**

See the [NumericRuler properties](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.decorator.numericruler-properties.html). In short:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.Color = [.8,.8,.8]; % grey as RGB triplet
ax.YAxis.Color = 'blue';     % blue as option keyword
```

**To change the grid lines**

You were right with `ax.GridColor`, but you have a semi-transparent grid by default so need to also set `ax.GridAlpha`.

```
ax = gca;
ax.GridColor = [0 0 0]; % Black as RGB, this is [0.15 0.15 0.15] by default (dark grey)
ax.GridAlpha = 1;       % Opaque, this is 0.15 by default (85% transparent)
```

**To make them the same**

```
ax = gca;
% Set the grid to be opaque
ax.GridAlpha = 1;
% Set them to be the same colour
myColour = [0.4, 0.7, 1]; % Any RGB triplet etc.
ax.GridColor = myColour;
ax.XAxis.Color = myColour;
ax.YAxis.Color = myColour;
```